# Facebook Interestial ads not showing

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network, facebook-ads

### I tries to show Facebook Interestial ads and banner ads in java with android studio.
Banner ads are shown but not Interestial.

- Below is the onCreate method inside "MainActivity.java" file-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_spin);
        initUI();
        // Initialize the Audience Network SDK
        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
        //interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this,  "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#1146100439159822_1161139187655947");
       // adView = new AdView(this, "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#1146100439159822_1161139187655977", AdSize.INTERSTITIAL);
        //adView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView (this, getString(R.string."IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#1146100439159822_1161139187655947"), AdSize.BANNER_320_50);

        adView = new AdView(this, "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#1038308803344159_1060854861089553", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

        // Find the Ad Container
        LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);

        // Add the ad view to your activity layout
        adContainer.addView(adView);

        // Request an ad
        adView.loadAd();
        //interstial fb ads
        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#1038308803344159_1038353880006318");

        adshow = findViewById(R.id.lol);

        // Create listeners for the Interstitial Ad
        InterstitialAdListener interstitialAdListener = new InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial ad displayed callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad displayed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial dismissed callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad dismissed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                // Ad error callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
                // Show the ad
                interstitialAd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad clicked!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                // Ad impression logged callback
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad impression logged!");
            }
        };

        // For auto play video ads, it's recommended to load the ad
        // at least 30 seconds before it is shown
        interstitialAd.loadAd(
                interstitialAd.buildLoadAdConfig()
                        .withAdListener(interstitialAdListener)
                        .build());


        adshow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               interstitialAd.loadAd();
               // interstitialAd.show();
            }
        });


    }
```

---

- Below is the "content_spin.xml" file where I have declared "Interstitial" button and the other for Banner ads.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/lol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
        android:text="Interstitial" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_container"
        android:layout_width="366dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

I am calling button from content_spin.xml file to show Interstitial ads.
Please help me how to show Interstitial ads on click of button from content_spin.xml file.